# Android/iOS chat push notifications only displaying first characters

Tags: push-notification, quickblox

Is there a way to display full chat message in push notifications?
Push notifications are only displaying first few characters of the message on both Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you are using automatic push notifications that were enabled in admin panel. In order to customise push notifications itself you need to create and send pushes by yourself (just disable automatic ones in admin panel).
Here is example on how to do it: http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-ios#Send_Push_Notifications_from_application_.28via_API.29